# How did Stern or Gerlach, of Stern-Gerlach experiment, create individual silver atoms? How were they accelerated?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, experimental-physics, magnetism

How, a century ago, could Stern and/or Gerlach KNOW that they had created single silver atoms?

How were they moved, or accelerated?

Answer (score 9):

Atomic spectroscopy was very advanced 100 years ago (1920s) and we must appreciate their intelligence. If a metal like silver is being heated to the extent of boiling in high vacuum, all you get is silver atoms. Just like when liquid water is strongly heated, one would get gaseous water molecules- each molecule is separate.

Stern and Gerlach write in  *Der experimentelle Nachweis des magnetischen Moments des Silberatoms.*  (The experimental proof of magnetic moments of silver atoms), Zeitschrift fur Physik 8.1 (1922): 110-111.

> Ein Silberatomstrahl von $1 / 20 \mathrm{~mm}$ Durchmesser geht in hohem Vakuum $(10^{-4}$ bis $10^{-5} \mathrm{~mm} \mathrm{Hg})$ hart an der Kante des schneidenförmigen Polschuhs eines Elektromagneten [Halbringelektromagnet nach du Bois<sup>2</sup>] vorbei. Der Strahl kommt aus einem kleinen $(1 / 2 \mathrm{~cm}^{3}$ Inhalt$)$, elektrisch geheizten, stählernen Öfchen durch eine im Deckel befindliche, $1 \mathrm{~mm}^{2}$ große, kreisförmige Offnung. Der Ofen ist von einem wassergekühlten Mantel umgeben. Etwa $1 \mathrm{~cm}$ vom Ofenloch entfernt passiert er die erste kreisförmige Blende $(1 / 20 \mathrm{~mm}$ Durchmesser$)$ in einem Platinblech. $3 \mathrm{~cm}$ hinter dieser passiert er eine zweite, ebensolche Blende, die sich am vorderen Ende des Schneidenpols des Elektromagneten befindet.

> A silver atom beam of $1 / 20 \mathrm{~mm}$  diameter passes in high vacuum $(10^{-4}$ to $10^{-5} \mathrm{~mm} \mathrm{ Hg})$  very close by the edge of the blade-shaped pole shoe of an electromagnet (half-ring electromagnet according to du Bois). The stream comes out of a small $(1 / 2 \mathrm{~cm}^{3}$ capacity$)$, electrically heated, steel furnace through a $1 \mathrm{~mm}^{2}$ sized circular opening located in the lid. The furnace is surrounded by a water-cooled jacket.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version) with some editing by @Hobbamok (native German speaker).

Comment: "hart" here means "very close" or "extremely close": The beam of silver atoms passes extremely closely by the edge of the blade-shaped pole shoe of an electromagnet.

Comment: @njuffa, I took the liberty of editing it myself, native German speaker as well and its a better translation (though now it may be a bit weird english lol)

Comment: Yes, the word "hart" was being mistranslated or perhaps the usage is old. It is still amazing that machine translations are so accurate now.

Comment: Small nitpick: I think typically metal ovens for spectroscopy don't heat to the boiling point, but just to where you get enough vapour pressure for your application (though it seems S&G didn't determine their oven temperature so cannot be sure). This also doesn't quite answer the question of how they knew that this only gives $\mathrm{Ag (g)}$ and not $\mathrm{Ag_n (g)}$ with $n > 1$, but I'm not sure if that is answerable because it was probably just common knowledge at that time.

Comment: @M.Farooq: I had to check. "hart" in English means a male red deer and doesn't seem to have had another meaning.

Comment: @Hobbamok It should be "passes very closely" as "close" modifies "passes" which means it is used as an adverb.

Comment: @Joshua, "hart" was quoted from the German text. which means hard. It was not an English word.

Comment: @Illama, it is the vacuum which ensures there are no dimers or n-mers of Ag.

Comment: @M.Farooq well, sputtering can happen in vacuum too right? But the question isn't why it happens, it's how Stern & Gerlach knew that it happens

Comment: @M.Farooq: Ah. Had it been translated hard I would have understood it. Hard in English has an old meaning of close.

Comment: @Joshua, What reference are you checking in English. I looked up the unabridged Oxford dictionary and I cannot see any meaning as "close" even in obsolete sense.

Comment: @M.Farooq: Oxford needs some fixing then. Here's one use: https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2063%3A8&version=KJV In fact I didn't look it up because it was already in my comprehended vocabulary.

Comment: @Joshu, Yes, just now found in the adverb section of OED where it says hard means "In close proximity (either in time or space), esp. so as to be adjacent; very near; immediately. Chiefly preceding a prepositional phrase, esp. with at ". Unabridged OED is huge.

Comment: @Joshua feel free to edit it then, the current version is from me and while I was in the US for 10 months, that was a couple of years ago and my English isn't as good anymore.  If you think most people would understand it (better) in english using "hard" just change it :) I think I heard that use as well but I wasn't sure if that was in English or German lol

Comment: @Hobbamok, "hard" as close, is good for Biblical English. Have a look at the example provided by Joshua. Please leave the translation as it is.

Answer (score 4):

For the second part of the question: they weren't accelerated in any way other than by heating, they formed what is known as a thermal beam. Atoms in the gaseous phase are always moving, with an average speed determined by their temperature. At higher pressures the atoms all collide with each other about every 100 nanometres, but under high vacuum they can travel long distances in straight paths. If you heat a sample (under vacuum) to the point that it produces a significant amount of vapour, and then let the vapour pass through two slits or apertures (called collimators) to select only the atoms going in a certain direction, you form a (low intensity) beam as shown in this sketch of the apparatus (with Cs instead of Ag), from [here](https://cronodon.com/Atomic/quantum_angular_momentum.html):

[image: Stern-Gerlach apparatus showing two apertures]

As long as the distances aren't too large and the temperature of the beam isn't extremely low, the effect of gravity on the trajectory of the beam is negligible and it can be treated as travelling in a straight line.